# Close popup window for Google OAuth2

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow, window.open, oauth-2.0

I have my oauth2 for Gmail open up in a popup using `newWindow = window.open(...)` and then when the user is done filling it out and hit 'allow' it redirects to my server where the tokens are retrieved and stored. Finally, the server returns 'Error' or 'Success' so the popup will just have that in it. Now on the Angular side I have this running.

```
checkConnect = setInterval(function() {
    try{
      if(newWindow.document.body.innerText === 'Success') {
        console.log('Success');
        newWindow.close();
        window.clearInterval(checkConnect);
      }else if(newWindow.document.body.innerText === 'Error') {
        console.log('We had an error!');
        newWindow.close();
        window.clearInterval(checkConnect);
      }else if(newWindow.closed) {
        console.log('WINDOW WAS closed');
        window.clearInterval(checkConnect);
      }
    }catch(e) {
      //console.log(e);
    }
}, 100);
```

This works sometimes and other times it fails. I also reuse this code for other Oauth providers, such as Dropbox.Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Well I couldn't figure it out by using a popup. However, I was able to over come this problem by just having the oauth page open in the same page and redirect back to the page I wanted the user on afterwards.

Also, there are libraries provided by google that open it for you in a popup and handle the closing.